# how to make a recyclerview infinite scroll (down / up)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've seen several infinite scroll examples for recyclerview, but they are all scrolling down.

what I want is to load my list again and again but regardless of whether the user scrolls from above or below.

Normal List

[image]

Scroll Up

[image]

Scroll Down

[image]

that way show the same ready over and over again with an infinite scroll

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is Pagination :)

you can do it by adding a scroll listener

```
    // Pagination
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener);
```

then

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                    && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                    && totalItemCount >= PAGE_SIZE) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

read this article for more things:
[medium](https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b)

Comment: What exactly does the loadmore function do, create a new instance of the adapter, send to update only the list of a global instance of the adapter ??

Comment: if you want the recycleview to load the same data again, make the **loadMoreItems** function get the same data and add them to the array then notify the adapter.